# maxDateproperty not working in ngx-daterangepicker-material in angular 14

Tags: angular, date-range, daterangepicker, ngx-daterangepicker-material

1. i am using ngx-daterangepicker-material (6.0.4) in angular 14, but maxDate property is not working
2. i am trying to disable future dates with ngx-daterangepicker-material

```
import { DaterangepickerDirective } from 'ngx-daterangepicker-material';
@ViewChild(DaterangepickerDirective) dateRangePicker: DaterangepickerDirective;

maxDate = moment();

<input type="text" #dateRangePicker ngxDaterangepickerMd [showCustomRangeLabel]="false" [alwaysShowCalendars]="true"
        [(ngModel)]="selectedDateRange" name="dateRangePicker" [ranges]="ranges" [linkedCalendars]="true"
        [showClearButton]="false" [keepCalendarOpeningWithRange]="true" [customRangeDirection]="true" (datesUpdated)="dateChanged($event)"
        [closeOnAutoApply]="false" [readonly]="true"
        [maxDate]="maxDate" hidden />
```